# Application hangs up randomly in jdbcTemplate for update

Tags: spring, jdbc

I am using `simpleJdbcTemplate` of Spring to execute update with query shown below:

```
update TABLE B JOIN 
(select Column1 from TABLE A
) C ON B.Column2 = C.Column3
set B.Column4 = 1
```

Transaction timeout is taking place.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

If the SQL execution is hanging, then either the database is doing a shedload of work trying to execute it, or you have a isolation lock on the required tables caused by another connection to the database from elsewhere.

This almost certainly has nothing to do with Spring, but without more information, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I had an uncommitted change to that record from sqldeveloper, committing made everything work as expected. still, hanging seems like the wrong behavior here, is there a timeout config for this somewhere?