# jdbcTemplate.update freezes

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I'm using a Spring JdbcTemplate without a "transactionManager" since I have mostly select to do.

When I try to call select queries from JUnit, it works, but when I try to call an "update", it freezes the test (no connection timeout, nothing, just waiting).

I've seen examples of jdbcTemplates insert/update without any transactionManager, but could it be the problem here ?

```
  public void insert(String param1, String param2) {

    String sql = "UPDATE MYTABLE SET name = :param1 where first_name = :param2";

    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate npJdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate);
    SqlParameterSource namedParameters = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("param1", param1).addValue("param2", param2);

    npJdbcTemplate.update(sql, namedParameters);
  }
```

Comment: How big is the table?  Does the query result in a full table scan making it take a long time?  Can the query be executed by some other tool?  Does the underlying data source provide connections with auto commit set to true?

Comment: I would try the same update with JDBC (PreparedStatement.executeUpdate) to see if it hangs without Spring or not.

Comment: The same query is instant in any SQL client. You may be right about the "autocommit" settings and the commit not occuring. Let's say my datasource is in autocommit = false, what should I do to commit manually ?

Comment: I get it I guess : If my datasource is not in "autocommit", I need a "transactionManager" to call the "commit" manually, right ?

Comment: In this example, he's using hikariCP like me, autocommit is not set (default is false) and update is occuring though : https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jdbc-mysql-hikaricp-example/

Comment: Maybe the problem is not in my code, but just that my test query in SQL client was not comitted : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911411/application-hangs-up-randomly-in-jdbctemplate-for-update

Comment: Just because you don't specify a transactionmanager doesn't mean there's not a transaction (unless you're specifically using a non-transactional database engine). it just means you're not getting the benefit of using spring to demarcate transaction boundaries, set isolation levels, etc.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I edit my question : transaction -> transactionManager.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here was I had passed the same update query on the same line in a SQL client (Oracle SQL developer) but it had not been committed in this client.

My JUnit had been stalled for 12 hours and right after I commit the query in SQL developer, the update occurred in the JUnit.

It had nothing to do with transaction management in the app or autocommit status of the datasource.

Comment: OMG, I'd upvote this more than once. Spent 2 hours searching the cause why a certain update call wasn't executed and I had still an open commit in my DataGrip application.

Comment: Exactly my case too! Thank you!

Comment: Been stuck with this issue for a day. Thankyou !

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I spent a day trying to understand what I was doing wrong.

Comment: Still relevant in 2023! Had to commit the query in Toad for Oracle in my case.